# Sending Form Data to external pjs Sketch in a Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, forms, canvas, processing.js

**EDIT**:

I did some more research and figured it out.  Changed html bit to:

```
Volume: 0%<input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" value="1" onchange="Processing.getInstanceById('spaceGame').changeVolume(this.value)">100%
```

(obviously I gave the canvas an id as well)

Changed function to:

```
void changeVolume(slideAmount){
    volume = slideAmount;
    alert("Volume was changed to "+volume*100+"%");//for testing
}
```

**Original question:**

I want the volume in my `processing.js` sketch to change when you change an html form.  Unfortunately, the form doesn't recognize the code I use in my canvas.  I am not good at html, and I do not know what to do to fix this.

```
<canvas width="600" height="600" data-processing-sources="spacegame.pde"></canvas>
<!--Later on...-->
    Volume: 0%
<input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" value="1" onchange="changeVolume(this.value)">100%
```

In `spacegame.pde` I have this code to process the form.

```
function changeVolume(slideAmount){
   volume = slideAmount;
   alert("Volume was changed to "+volume*100+"%");//for testing
}
```

My input form isn't seeing my pde file, so firebug gives me this error:  `ReferenceError: changeVolume is not defined`

Please tell me how I can make my canvas code recognized by the input tag.  Thank you.

Comment: if You add your own response as an answer, you can accept it.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me.  I tried to do it earlier, but it said I couldn't do it yet and I forgot to do it later.

Comment: two things: you can also catch the sketch reference in a way that you don't call functions before it's available. See http://processingjs.org/articles/PomaxGuide.html, search for `This leaves us with needing to make sure that we really do tell the sketch what Javascript is, which we'll do as follows on the page`. The JS after that is what you want. Secondly, try to steer clear of `alert()` and either use `console.log` in JS, or `println` in Processing setting. Alert locks up a tab or even browser, whereas console logs and printlns do not.

Comment: 1) Thanks, that is useful.  2) I know, as I said in a comment, I used the alert for testing (I don't want to have to listen for the change, and alert is more convenient than console.log).  It would very annoying if the volume alerted you whenever you changed it.  (Now I have an element that displays the volume)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my question.

I did some more research and figured it out. Changed html bit to:

```
Volume: 0%<input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" value="1" onchange="Processing.getInstanceById('spaceGame').changeVolume(this.value)">100%
```

(obviously I gave the canvas an id as well)

Changed function to:

```
void changeVolume(slideAmount){
    volume = slideAmount;
    alert("Volume was changed to "+volume*100+"%");//for testing
}
```